# combine rows of multiple arrays of a cell to one new array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, merge, cell

There is a cell with five arrays. Each array consits of two rows and 30 columns. Now i want one array with the values in the first rows of the arrays merged.

```
cellC{1,1} = arrayA1 = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
cellC{1,2} = arrayA2 = [11 12 13; 14 15 16]
....
```

I want to get the array

```
[1 2 3 11 12 13]
```

Indexing like the following does not work:

```
cellC{1, 1:5}(1,:)
```

I thought of a for-loop but there must be a simpler solution. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `{:}` indexing to create a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) that you can then pass to `cat` to concatenate all of the cell contents horizontally. You can then select out the first row from the resulting matrix.

```
tmp = cat(2, cellC{:});
result = tmp(1,:);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot!